# Local Background image css won't override stylesheet css

Tags: html, css, background

I have a universal stylesheet which references a universal background image. I now want to make different background images for several of the pages on my website.

I have tried adding local style to the class tag, with `!important` to override the stylesheet. While this stops the original background image from displaying, it won't display the new image.

Current code is:

```
<div class="main_wrapper" style="float: left; background: 
     url("/images/live_body_bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed top right !important; 
     width:100%;">
```

Stylesheet code is as follows:

```
.main_wrapper {
    padding: 0px 0 30px 0;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/body_bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed top right #000;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 3px #fec500 solid;
}
```

Please advise...

Comment: Are you using WordPress by any chance?

Comment: did you check the path ? your div image path starts with a / while your css one doesnt ?

Comment: It IS a wordpress theme, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes in your url is prematurely terminating the style information. You can use single quotes for the background url instead of the double quotes.

```
<div class="main_wrapper" style="float: left; background: 
 url('/images/live_body_bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed top right !important; 
 width:100%;">
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Have changed the quotes to single quotes but it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: This code changes the background colour but will not display the image: <div class="main_wrapper" style="background: url('images/live_body_bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed bottom right #9b9b9b !important;">

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The file path was wrong. When I put the entire URL in single quotes, the background image displays correctly.